# Slide transition for android activities

Tags: android, animation, transition, sliding

I want to create an app similar to Snapchat where I Have three activities; most left is a full screen camera, middle is main activity that contain an action bar and a list of items, most right is personal profile.

What I need is a way for transition between the three activities that simulate sliding, I mean swiping from left to right or vice versa should show a peek of the other activity running.

It's because I need to change the action bar for each activity and I want the camera to be in full screen.

any tips on making the transition and the full screen camera view would be great folks.

Comment: why not start trying for yourself and then ask for help when you get stuck?

Comment: I've been trying for 2 days, couldn't come up with anything or find anything helpful on the web

Comment: use three fragments for different uses...load them individually and control them accordingly

Comment: @AtishAgrawal that's what I did, thanks alot for taking the time to answer